# sed to remove section of text from a variable

Tags: shell, variables, sed

So I think I've cracked the regex but just can't crack how to get sed to make the changes. I have a variable which is this:

```
MAKEVAR = EPICS_BASE=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/3.16/base IPAC=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/3.16/support/ipac SNCSEQ=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/3.16/support/seq
```

(All one line). But I want to delete the particular section defining IPAC so my regex looks like this:

```
(IPAC.+\s)
```

I know from using this tool that that should be correct:

https://www.regextester.com/98103

However when I run different iterations of trying out sed like:

```
sed 's/(IPAC.+\s)/\&/g' <<< "$MAKEVAR"
```

And then echo out MAKEVAR, the IPAC section still exists.

How can I update a particular section of text in a shell variable to remove a section beginning with IPAC up until the next space?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

regextester (or any other online tool) is a great way to verify that a regexp works in that online tool. Unfortunately that doesn't mean it'll work in any given command-line tool. In particular your regexp includes `\s` which is specific to PCREs and some GNU tools, and uses `(...)` to delineate capture groups but that's only used in EREs and PCREs, not BREs such as sed supports by default where you'd have to use `\(...\)`, and your replacement text is using '&' which is telling sed you want to replace the string that matches the regexp with a literal `\&` when in fact you just want to remove it.

This is how to do what I think you're trying to do using any sed:

```
$ sed 's/IPAC[^ ]* //' <<< "$MAKEVAR"
EPICS_BASE=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/3.16/base SNCSEQ=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/3.16/support/seq
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, found a workaround:
MAKEVAR=$(sed -E 's/(IPAC.+ipac)//' <<<"$MAKEVAR")

Answer (score 0):

Use a shorter

```
MAKEVAR=$(sed 's/IPAC.*ipac//' <<< "$MAKEVAR")
```

`IPAC.*ipac` matches all the way from first `IPAC` to last `ipac`. The matched text is removed from the text.